# VBA SQL doesn't recognize assigned variables

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I feel like things are always more complicated than they really need to be.

I also feel like that could very well be entirely from my own lack of experience...

Purpose:
I'm working once again on printing things from MS Access through Bartender. I have now been asked to create a form on which the user would enter a Material # along with how many wires are associated with that number, and which would then print out a tag for each wire, reading both the Material and Wire #s.

Procedure:
I'm using a table in a foreign database, from which Bartender gets its data to print. I have an SQL statement to clear that table, then another to fill it with the relevant information in a DO...UNTIL loop.

Code:

```
Private Sub Next_Click()

Dim PrintLabel As Variant
Dim ClearTable As String
Dim FillTable As String

    Dim strMaterial As String
    Dim intWire As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    strMaterial = [txtMaterial]
    intWire = [txtWire]
    i = 1

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    ClearTable = "DELETE * from G:\OPS\ZShared\PrintData.accdb.PrintData"

    DoCmd.RunSQL ClearTable

    Do

         FillTable = "INSERT INTO G:\OPS\ZShared\PrintData.accdb.PrintData ([Material], [Wire #]) VALUES (strMaterial, intWire)"

         DoCmd.RunSQL FillTable

         intWire = intWire - 1

    Loop Until intWire = 0

    PrintLabel = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Seagull\Bartender Suite\bartend.exe /F=G:\OPS\ZShared\Tags.btw /P /X")
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    DoCmd.Close

End Sub
```

Problem:
When I run this, it executes fine until I enter the DO...UNTIL loop. From there, it prompts me to enter strMaterial and intWire until kingdom come, meaning it somehow is dropping or ignoring the assignments I give to those two variables earlier in the code.

Potential Points of Interest
Neither entering 1 nor 0 for intWire leads to the loop breaking, nor does it break after the proper number of iterations to begin with. Also, whatever data is entered into the prompts for strMaterial and intWire are written to the foreign database as they are supposed to be.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"INSERT INTO PrintData ([Material], [Wire #]) VALUES (strMaterial, intWire)"
```

With strMaterial and intWire being part of the Sql string, Access assumes that they are parameters and asks you for their value.

What you want to do:

```
"INSERT INTO PrintData ([Material], [Wire #]) VALUES ('" & strMaterial & "', " & intWire & ")"
```

so the values of the variables are used in the Sql string, not their names.
strMaterial must be enclosed in '' because it's a string.

Or even better: create a parameterized query instead of constructing a dynamic Sql string, to avoid Sql injection.